# Syntax Error: What's wrong with the below code

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous-javascript

Help me resolve the below code showing syntax error. I know there is definitely some problem. How to write the below checkInventory order with the help of arrow functions.

```
const {checkInventory} = require('./library.js');

const order = [['sunglasses', 0], ['bags', 2]];

const handleSuccess = (resolvedValue) => {
    console.log(resolvedValue);
};

const handleFailure = (rejectReason) => {
    console.log(rejectReason);
};

checkInventory(order)=new Promise(resolvedValue, rejectReason){
    if(resolvedValue)
        return handleSuccess;
    else
        return handleFailure;
};
```

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: `checkInventory(order) = <expression>` You can only assign to variable names

Comment: what is this syntax `new Promise(resolvedValue, rejectReason){}`?

Answer (score 0):

That code is part of a tutorial from [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/introduction-to-javascript/lessons/promises/exercises/onfulfilled-onrejected?action=resume_content_item)
whereby the `checkInventory()` returns a promise and a `.then()` is attached to it
and the two handlers i.e `handleSuccess()` and `handleFailure()` are passed as arguments. Therefore the code will look like this:

```
checkInventory(order).then(handleSuccess, handleFailure);
```